# Finding Text With specified font in MS word using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word in c#

Tags: c#, ms-word

I have a document in which it is showing Mangal (Body CS) font in fontlist box.I want to find all the text in the document which has mangal font.
I used following code:

```
Range rng = ActiveDocument.Content;
Find findobj = rng.Find;
findobj.ClearFormatting();
findobj.Wrap = Word.WdFindWrap.wdFindStop;
findobj.Format = true;
findobj.Forward = true;
findobj.Text = "";
findobj.Font.Name = "Mangal";
bool findresult = findobj.Execute();
```

When i use this code it failed to find the text which is showing Mangal (Body CS) font.So how to find this kind of font text ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to "find" this font as an end-user, in the Word application?

If yes, record a macro while performating the Find then compare the parameters and values used with your code.